# Why is it saying name not defined?

Tags: python, function

So i am creating a stock ranker that takes data from twitter. I am having an issue where i am getting the error

```
NameError: name 'tweets' is not defined
```

This is my code

```
while True:
    sleep(120 - time() % 120)
    def searchTwit():
        tweets = api.search("#stocks" or "#daytrading",count=100)
        return tweets


    def getTicker(tweets):
        for tweet in tweets:
            if "$" in tweet.text:
                x = tweet.text.split()
                for i in x:
                    if i.startswith("$") and i[1].isalpha():
                        i.strip(".")
                        i.upper()
                        tickList.append(i)

    # print(var_string)
    def retrieveTickers():
        for i in tickList:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO master.dbo.TickerTable (TickerName) VALUES (?);', (i))
        conn.commit()

        # thing to run
    searchTwit()
    getTicker(tweets)
    print("getting Tickers")
    retrieveTickers()
    print("sending tickers")
    print(tickList)
    tickList=[]
    print(tickList)
```

I am not sure weather all of this should be in a while loop or not, and I am also confused why i am getting this error when one of my functions returns "tweets".

Comment: `tweets = searchTwit()`

Comment: When you `return` something you don't return the variable name. You return its value, so you should still assign a name to it.

Comment: Btw, functions should be defined outside of a loop

Comment: Okay thank you guys, I had the functions outside before but I got confused with this erro